# How to parse XML and create a tree structure in Perl

Tags: perl, cpan

I am parsing a XML file with [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple). Is there any way to get a tree form from the XML? If so please explain with example or suggest a CPAN package.

I would like to know which tag I have to process after `column` and so on.

There is no sequence for the tags. The `column` tag can appear after `Table` or `display_name` many times.

```
Tab
    column
    Table
        column
    display_name
    column
    display_name
```

XML:

```
<Tab>
    <column>
        <display_name>xyz</display_name>
        <display_name>pqr</display_name>
    </column>
    <Table>
        <column><display_name>Department</display_name></column>
    </Table>
    <display_name>abc</display_name>
    <column>pwd</column>
    <display_name>jack</display_name>
</Tab>
```

output with XML::Simple:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'Table' => {
    'column' => {
      'display_name' => 'Department'
    }
  },
  'display_name' => [
    'abc',
    'jack'
  ],
  'column' => [
    {
      'display_name' => [
        'xyz',
        'pqr'
      ]
    },
    'pwd'
  ]
};
```

Expected o/p:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'column' => {
    'display_name' => [
      'xyz',
      'pqr'
    ]
  }
  'Table' => {
    'column' => {
      'display_name' => 'Department'
    }
  }, 
  'display_name' => 'abc',
  'column' => 'pwd',
  'display_name' =>'jack'
};
```

I know a hash with same keys isn't possible. Please suggest a way that I can maintain the sequence of tags and will be able to print them.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Is there a reason you need to do it without using `Dumper`?

Comment: @Steve: can't use dumper since traversal is necessary to print html code from above xml.

Comment: @Ganesh You will never get your expected output in Perl.  You have a key collision since you have `display_name` and `column` twice as a key.  What XML::Simple is giving you is correct.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show the complete input XML and the output you desire.

Answer (score 5):

XML::LibXML creates a tree with no loss of information.

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $tree = $parser->parse_file($qfn);
```

You can generate the output you specified from there. (I don't know why you'd want to, since the Perl code you want for output would lose data if run.)

Comment: Hey thanks for reply will you please provide more details example for above input file using XML::LibXML. what is $qfn?

Comment: The qualified file name of an XML file, i.e. an absolute path to an XML file, or a path relative to the current work directory to an XML file.

Answer (score 2):

I used [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm) for same file

```
#!/usr/sbin/perl
use  XML::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;

my $Filename = "abc.xml";

my $Parser = new XML::Parser( Style => 'tree' );

my $Tree = $Parser->parsefile( $Filename );

print Dumper( $Tree );
```

If there is another way to get desired output please suggest.