# Catch specific variable and print his value

Tags: perl, sed, awk

Want to catch a specific variable, in this case `DataIp`, and to print it's value.

Data:

```
<UnitInstance DataIp="10.1.1.1" Hostname="crg11" ID="30">
```

Output:

```
10.1.1.1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16746944/223226

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example....

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=DataIp=\")[^\"]+' file
10.1.1.1
```

We look for whatever coming after `DataIp="` and print everything till we find a `"`. Note that the double quotes need to be escaped: `\"`.

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.*DataIp=\"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/g' file
10.1.1.1
```

We catch the word after `DataIp` and then print it.

---

Considering the general situation in which we want to catch the first word wrapped by `"`, we can also do it...

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F\" '{print $2}' file
10.1.1.1
```

We split the records in fields based on `"` delimiter and print the 2nd one.

With `cut`:

```
$ cut -d'"' -f2 file
10.1.1.1
```

We split the records in fields based on `"` delimiter and print the 2nd one.

Comment: good examples, but what about in Data we have:
`<UnitInstance DataIp="10.1.1.1" Hostname="crg11" ID="30">`
`crg-get.xml` how to print and value after when I get the hostname.

Comment: why the greedy asterisk instead of a `+` ?

Comment: @KalinBorisov please explain it again, I don't understand what you exactly mean. If necessary, update your question with new input / expected output.

Comment: @Paulchenkiller for which case do you mean?

Comment: I think the latest example helping me a lot

Comment: the problem with the last three examples you provide is that they don't check for the header he specified, but if the guy liked it who am I to say otherwise...

Comment: Completely true, @user2141046 I somehow overlooked it. Just updated the `sed` version to check it. `cut` and `awk` are not updated, but moved to a "most general solution". Thanks

Comment: @fedorqui the first. `'(?<=DataIp=\")[^\"]*'`

Comment: @Paulchenkiller so it is better to do it `(?<=DataIp=\")[^\"]+`? I am new on these regex, could you explain why it is better? thanks!

Comment: Perl regular expressions normally match the longest string possible. In this case, the longest part is 2 characters long. Internally the regex engine need to take the whole string. when you use the `+` instead, the regex isn't greedy and stop when the first match occur. (its not a big problem in this case, but when you have a long file with thousands matches, it can be a safe of seconds.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation, @Paulchenkiller. Now it makes sense the concept `greedy` for `*`, as it wants aaaall the line. Just updated my answer with `+` instead. Thanks!

Comment: Can't open the link, can you check if it is a git permissions issue?

Comment: Well, i can present you the results: the non -greedy version need about half the time and 6% less space

Comment: Good one, will keep it in mind for the future. Thanks @Paulchenkiller