# Sum and mean values within XML tags using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, sum, mean, median

I have a bunch of tags like this within an XML file:

```
<Key Time="47" TT=Xr="485" Yr="311" Yc="183" />
```

I would like to get the sum, min-max, median and mean of Yc and Yr in all tags and also within a limited number of tags (say those in lines 10 and 30).

Is it possible to do this using Perl?

Comment: try with xml parsing first, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16746944/223226

Answer (score 2):

XML does not have a concept of line numbers. To access values in XML, use an XML Parser like [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML).

Assuming your data were

```
<Keys>
  <Key Time="47" Xr="485" Yr="311" Yc="183" />
  <Key Time="47" Xr="485" Yr="123" Yc="381" />
  <Key Time="47" Xr="485" Yr="456" Yc="190" />
  <Key Time="47" Xr="485" Yr="322" Yc="182" />
  <Key Time="47" Xr="485" Yr="223" Yc="165" />
</Keys>
```

We could parse it like

```
use strict; use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $the_data);
```

Then we can access the attributes via XPath expressions:

```
my (@yr, @yc);
for my $key ($xml->findnodes('/Keys/Key')) {
  push @yr, $key->findvalue('./@Yr');
  push @yc, $key->findvalue('./@Yc');
}
```

If you only want to access a certain number of `Key`s, you can refine the XPath expression or count in the Perl code, or use a slice:

```
for my $key ( ($xml->findnodes(...))[10..30] ) { ... }
```

After all such values were collected, doing a bit statistics is trivial.

For `sum`, `min`, and `max`, you can use the functions from `List::Util`.

**Edit:** The `Statistics::Descriptive` module is awesome:

```
use Statistics::Descriptive;
use feature 'say'; # for the "say" function. Available since perl5 v10.

my $yr = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();
$yr->add_data(@yr);

say "mean: ",   $yr->mean;
say "median: ", $yr->median;
say "min: ",    $yr->min;
say "max: ",    $yr->max;
say "sum: ",    $yr->sum;
```

This module can easily be installed from CPAN.

Comment: For median and mean, [Statistics::Descriptive::Full](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics::Descriptive) or maybe [Statistics::Descriptive::Discrete](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics::Descriptive::Discrete) (assuming there are few  values repeated multiple times) may fit. (Both can cover min, max, and sum as well).

Comment: Many, many thanks. Still, I am sorry to be so "newbie", but could you tell me what functions they are?

Comment: It does not work. Am I missing something? How does the script "know" what files I am working with?

Comment: @LuizLacerda I have no idea what code you are currently using. I tested a combination of my code snippets and it produced nice output. If you want to load the XML from a filehandle you could do `XML::LibXML->new(IO => $the_filehandle)`.

Comment: This is what I get: Global symbol "$the_data" requires explicit package name at ScriptParaOrientacao.pl line 5.
Execution of ScriptParaOrientacao.pl aborted due to compilation errors. Line 5 is this one: my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $the_data);

Comment: Oh dear. Of course, you first have to declare your variables and assign a value to them. I'm sorry I was not perfectly clear. I will not write out the whole script for you, but you should be able to manage this after a good Perl tutorial or two (See the [Perl tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) for a few recommendations).